# R wont knit to html or pdf with SQL chunks. Error in eval(x, envir = envir) : object 'connection' not found

Tags: sql, r

````
connection <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "AmericasCup.sqlite")
dbWriteTable(connection, "results", results, overwrite=TRUE)

```{sql connection=connection, output.var = "outQ6"}
SELECT Code, 
       SUM(Result = 'Win' ) AS Wins,
       SUM(Result = 'Loss') AS Losses
FROM results
GROUP BY Code
````

Everything runs fine but when I try knit to html or pdf I get the following error:
[image]
Line 79 is: SELECT Code,

Can anyone tell me what the problem is here, I have tried to research this but cant find anything similar, though I suspect it has something to do with my '''{sql connection=connection, output.var - "outQ6"} setup.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it, I put this in my r setup instead and now just do {sql} to start sql chunk.

```
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)
connection <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "AmericasCup.sqlite")
knitr::opts_chunk$set(connection = "connection")
```